# Catch exceptions from external libraries in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

There is some way to catch eexceptions from external libraries?

I have an application in VB.NET, and all the code is controlled by Try..Catch blocks.

Also I am using some external libraries, some of them, GMap.net libraries.

The problem that I have with the libraries of GMap is that one of its libraries is throwing an exception which I am not able to control, because I have not access to the code of that librarie.

It is a 'Collection Modified..' exception, and maybe the developers of this librarie, in some place of the code, they forgot to control it.

now, what happens is that some times, my application throws an uncontrolled exception, which becames from that librarie, and I don't know how to catch it.

For sure there is some way to catch exceptions from external libraries, but I am not able to find the answer, so any help will be very grateful.

Here is the uncontrolled exception thrown by the application:

- No se controló System.InvalidOperationException
- HResult=-2146233079
- Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
- Source=mscorlib
- StackTrace:
- at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
- at System.Collections.Generic.List1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
- at System.Collections.Generic.List1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
- at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapOverlay.OnRender(Graphics g)
- at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.OnPaintOverlays(Graphics g)
- at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.DrawGraphics(Graphics g)
- at GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
- at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, -Int16 layer)
- at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
- at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
- at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
- at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
- at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
- at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
- at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
- InnerException:

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand. You catch exceptions from external libraries the same way as in your code: with a `try`-block.

Comment: Thanks @sloth for your answer. If I have to do it using try-catch block, where I must place the try-catch block in this cases? I have all the application controlled by try-catch blocks, and when this exception appears, any of the catch in the application fires. I have edited my question with the exception I receive if it could help. Also the exception does not give me any information about lines in the code..

Comment: I don't know how your code or the library in question look like, but maybe subscribing to the [UnhandledException Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) maybe be of some help to you.

Comment: Are you modifying any collections linked to/used by the library? You might want to report an issue [on its GitHub page](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/issues), best is if you can include some code that reproduces the problem (start a new project and try it again), or at the very least a description of when it happens.

Comment: After quickly looking through the library's source code it appears to be related to the `GMapControl.Overlays` collection. Presumably you are changing this (perhaps in a background thread?) while the control is trying to redraw itself. Might be worth to report, though you ought to include some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It is not an exception that you can catch, all of the code lives in the library and the framework.  The Application.ThreadException normally provides a notification but in this case if won't be raised because the Paint event handler has a backstop for unhandled exceptions, you should see the Red Cross of Failure.  You must assume it is your code that causes it, the standard way to do this is by using a worker thread to update the data that the control uses.  You can't, it is not thread-safe.